# Selecting multiple unique index column pairs form dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to slice a dataframe from two equal length lists of index values and column values. For example, suppose I have the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[100]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Now, I want to select multiple index/column pairs from this data from two arrays, one containing the index values and the other containing the column values. Let's say my pairs are

```
x=np.array([0,2])
y=np.array(['a','b'])
```

My desired output is an array of 2 values: `[1,8]`

If I try using `.loc`, instead I get every combination. What I want is the specific pairs as above

```
df.loc[x,y]

Out[106]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
2  7  8
```

Is there an easy way to do this without messy loops?

Comment: Use `df2.lookup(x, y)`

Comment: note that from pandas 1.2, `lookup` is deprecated.  You could try ``[df2.at[val] for val in zip(x, y)]``

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but .lookup is deprecated and I'd prefer not to use a for loop, as my actual dataset is several thousand rows. Is there a merge operation or something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take adventage of [NumPy integer indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) and use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to 'map' the selected columns names to numbers:

```
>>> df.values[x, np.searchsorted(df.columns, y)]
array([1, 8])
```

Comment: @Alex Nice! Glad to help